# QOpenGLWidget and Qt platform

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, platform, vnc

I started the a `QT`(i.e: QT13.2) GUI program by:

```
qt_gui_program -platform vnc
```

But the program outputed a lot of warning:

```
Warning: File:() Line:(0) (08:23:28) QOpenGLWidget is not supported on this platform.
Warning: File:() Line:(0) (08:25:08) This plugin does not support createPlatformOpenGLContext!
Warning: File:() Line:(0) (08:25:08) QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
```

It seems that `QOpenGLWidget` is not supported when the platform is `vnc`.
I have some related questions:

1.What causes `QOpenGLWidget` can't be supported when the platform is `vnc`?

2.How can I know whether a Class is supported by a specific platform or not?

3.I have to access the GUI on a remote computer. Is there any method besides setting the platform as `linux/X11`?

Comment: From the error messages it looks like the vnc environment set up simply doesn't support OpenGL.  You could try creating a vnc server manually and then running your application in that server.

Comment: @G.M. What causes QOpenGLWidget can't be supported when the platform is set as `vnc`?

Comment: As far as I'm aware It could be due to any number of things -- possibly platform dependent.  Sorry I can't provide more info.